# Why is copying pairs slower than copying structs?

Tags: c++, performance, struct, move, std-pair

I wanted to show my team why move semantics can save resources. So I wrote some code to get some numbers for the talk. However, during this work I found something interesting which I did not fully understand. Copying a vector of pairs took substantially longer than copying a vector of an equivalent struct.
Any ideas why?

Output:

```
std::pair<int,int>
===============
- sizeof type: 8
- sizeof container: 16
- copy = 80392 microseconds
- move = 6 microseconds

PAIR
====
- sizeof type: 8
- sizeof container: 16
- copy = 6377 microseconds
- move = 8 microseconds
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

template <typename T>
void
MoveCopyComp()
{
    std::vector<T> list;
    T dummy;
    std::cout << "- sizeof type: " << sizeof(T) << "\n";
    std::cout << "- sizeof container: " << sizeof(list) << "\n";
    for (int num = 0; num < 1000000; ++num)
        list.push_back(dummy);

    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<T> copy = list;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<T> movement = std::move(list);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "- copy = "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1 - t0).count()
              << " microseconds\n";
    std::cout << "- move = "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
              << " microseconds\n";
}

struct PAIR
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "std::pair<int,int>\n===============\n";
    MoveCopyComp<std::pair<int,int>>();
    std::cout << "\nPAIR\n====\n";
    MoveCopyComp<PAIR>();
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ins and outs of copy vs move. Wouldn't a copy require the calling of a constructor, while both move and the copying of structs don't?

Comment: Is this a fully-optimized build? You're also benchmarking over too short a period of time to be statistically meaningful. You should have tests that run for at least a minute to account for short bursts in CPU performance due to cache issues or CPU throttling. Does reversing the order impact the results?

Comment: Whats your build command line. You _must_ be in an optimised build to get meaningful results.

Comment: compiling your code with ```--std=c++17 -O2``` flags and increased loop size to 10000000, i get following result: pair<int, int> -- 53407 microseconds, PAIR -- 64563 microseconds

Comment: With -O2, I get consistently around 10% lower times for `std::pair` when averaging over 100 or 1000 runs, even with your small vector. There are a few instances (2-5 % of them) where `pair` is slower, but that can be explained by factors outside the program, such as OS scheduling and hardware. Determining whether those 10% are an actual difference would require further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Oh face palm! Mike Vine hit it right on the shnoz.
I was using my debug build settings and not optimised.

Here are my optimised results for the same code:

```
std::pair<int,int>
===============
- sizeof type: 8
- sizeof container: 12
- copy = 2388 microseconds
- move = 0 microseconds

PAIR
====
- sizeof type: 8
- sizeof container: 12
- copy = 2672 microseconds
- move = 0 microseconds
```

Thanks everyone for the comments :)